# Is it good pratice to use an hidden TextView as a identifier?

Tags: android

I'm noob at Android Development. I would like to know if is it good praticse to use an hidden TextView as a identifier.

I frequently receive Json data, and I put the ID from the row inside a textview and I turn it invisible. I use this trick when I'm using a listview with clickable items.

Is it wrong to do that? Is there a better way to do the same thing?

Thanks.

Comment: *Is it wrong to do that?* - it's not ok because you add one extra view(which costs in terms of performance) mostly for nothing. Every view has a `setTag()` method which you could use to add an additional piece of information to it.

Comment: Why not store it in a separate "data" class?

Comment: You already have an id here: `protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, final int position, long id)`

Comment: One downside might be that you mix up view and logic (if you declare the TextView in xml) when it's not really needed, and this goes against the design principles

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys... I will change it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To sum up the comments you've received:

> I would like to know if is it good praticse to use an hidden TextView
>   as a identifier.

No, it's not. Declaring view elements to be used in your program logic would violate the principles of separating view (xml) from your application logic (java). Also, as Luksprog pointed out;

> It's not ok because you add one extra view (which costs in terms of
>   performance) mostly for nothing.

Instead, use the Android framework callback method `onListItemClick` as suggested by Der Gol...lum:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    //do something cleaver with the ID parameter
}
```